# Blank pages in MS ACCESS Reports

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to hide the blank pages generated by setting fields under **Non visible** function  on an Access Report?
For exemple, due seleccion 1 made by user ona  form then 10 fields are shown in the  access report. But when selection 2 is made, only 3 would be visible, but the 7 rest would be "non visible", therefor generate a blank page/space... is it a way to program on VBA to hide this empty space, or to adjust the page to what is "visible"?

I added the suggested .left property in the report code, but the blank area doesn't seems to shrink...

```
 Me!Cap4.Report!ToolConfDesc.Left = 0
 Me!Cap4.Report!ToolConfDescpiclbl.Left = 0
 Me!Cap4.Report!ToolConfDescpic.Left = 0
 Me!Cap4.Report!ToolConfDescpiclbl.Left = 0

 Me!Cap4.Report!DandFDesc.Left = 0
 Me!Cap4.Report!DandFDesclbl.Left = 0
 Me!Cap4.Report!DandFTable.Left = 0
 Me!Cap4.Report!DandFTablelbl.Left = 0

 Me!Cap4.Report!MoSDesc.Left = 0
 Me!Cap4.Report!MoSDesclbl.Left = 0
 Me!Cap4.Report!MoSDescPic.Left = 0
 Me!Cap4.Report!MoSDescPiclbl.Left = 0
```

Comment: Did you also add the `Me.Width = ...` ?

Comment: no, cos the suggestion said only .left = 0 i must add  the  .width = 0 property also??

Comment: Not 0. Please check the last line of my answer.

Comment: ahh yes i had set both, but i still get the blank space...i have also tried to set can shrink and can grow properties to yes, but does nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event procedure where you set the fields invisible (I assume `Report_Open`):

- Set `.Left` of all invisible fields to 0, so they don't get in the way when reducing the report width
- Set the report width small enough that no blank pages are generated, e.g.

```vb
Me.Width = 17 * 567  ' 17 cm * 567 Twips/cm
```

Comment: Like  Me!FieldName.Visible = False and under Me!FieldName.Left = 0 ??

Comment: should it shrink the space? its seems not to work :(

Comment: @PiaA: please edit your question and add the code you have now.

Comment: The code i posted is the one that doesnt work... is like it doesnt shrink my controls, once they re empty.